# Unable to launch Android VM

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, haxm

I had issues with VS2015 before and eventually had to reinstall my OS. So after that, I installed VS2015 + Xamarin on my Windows 10 PC. Before I had reinstalled my OS, and before it went all haywire, everything was working fine. The AVMs launched and everything worked well. Now, apparently, even after reinstallation on my OS, the ghosts of the errors don't seem to go away.

This is what's going on:

When I create a simple project, and I debugged the sample code in it, I got this error:

[image]

So, naturally, I used the x86 version VM. Then I got this error:

[image]

I dug around in Stack Overflow and the other parts of internet and tried multiple things, but nothing seems to have worked. I really would liked to have this sorted out so I can go ahead with my project. Any help is appreciated.

1. I've tried to remove/reinstall HAXM and
2. Tried to Install Visual Studio Android emulator

Nothing seems to have worked. With the latter, the debugging is SLOW. It just doesn't do anything. The emulator launches fine, but nothing happens after that. No, I don't get the `Stop Debugging` button, so..

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I noticed this: In the Android Emulator for Visual Studio, the app was actually there. Just that it hadn't launched. I had t manually launch it. The 'Clicker app actually worked'. Fine! So, what do I do now? How do I know if it's all working?? Also, is it supposed to behave that way? Because as I remember it, when I was doing a Windows phone app development project, it launched the app directly into the emulator. When I first started to fiddle with it (before my computer was formatted), it did the same. Please help!

Comment: So if it is working fine, why isn't the x86 emulator working? It still throws that error.